# How can i prevent the last loop of the while if i'm printing in it

Tags: python, loops, math, while-loop

Here is a piece of code to get an example.

```
counter = 0
sum = 0

numbers= int(input('give 10 numbers \n'))
while counter<10:

  sum= sum+numbers
  counter= counter+1
  numbers= int(input('give 10 numbers \n' + str((10-counter)) + ' to go \n' ))

if counter == 10:
    print('The sum of those numbers is' + str(sum))
```

Now its printing this:

```
Give 10 numbers
Give 10 numbers 9 to go
Give 10 numbers 8 to go
...
Give 10 numbers 0 to go
```

I want to delete the last printed sentence because the sum will be right, but it still needs to loop because it has to sum the number. Is there a solution to stop the printing, but not the loop?

I hope you guys understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you want an initial prompt that is different from the subsequent prompts, then change where you do the loop control testing (I have also made the code somewhat more "Pythonic"):

```
counter = 0
sum = 0

numbers = int(input('give 10 numbers\n'))
while True:
    sum += numbers
    counter += 1
    if counter == 10:
        break
    numbers = int(input('give 10 numbers \n' + str((10-counter)) + ' to go \n' ))

print('The sum of those numbers is', sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# set up a variable to hold the number of answers provided
counter = 0

# set up a variable to store the total sum of the numbers entered
sum_ = 0

# set up a variable to store the number of questions left (number of inputs pending)
numbers_remaining = 10

# while the counter variable is not equal to a value of 10, we enter the while loop
while counter != 10:

    # we take input inside the while loop
    # we are printing the below statement, indicating the total number of inputs we want (10) and the number of inputs remaining
    print('Give 10 numbers,', numbers_remaining, 'to go')

    # upon entering a number, we may decrement the number of inputs required by 1
    numbers_remaining-=1

    # we obtain input below
    number = int(input('enter number: '))

    # we increment the counter variable by 1, storing the number of inputs provided
    counter+=1

    # we add the input number to the sum variable
    sum_+=number

# we removed the 'if' statement and condition, because a while loop will execute repeatedly until a Boolean False is received

# upon termination of the program, we print the sum of the values entered
print('The sum of those numbers is:', sum_)
```

Comment: Hi, could you maybe add some comments or descriptions, what you changed in comparison to the original, and why?

Comment: Hi @jottbe, Sure I will do that now.